# How to rearrange the column position in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I change the column position to first using ALTER query in MySQL table?

Comment: Columns are all named - why does it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your column at first position, you should use

```
ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY COLUMN yourColumnName varchar(50) FIRST
```

For example, if your table is

```
Employee{FirstName,LastName,EmpId}
```

And if you want to move EmpId to first position

```
ALTER TABLE Employee MODIFY COLUMN EmpId varchar(15) FIRST;
```

Comment: I removed the first column specified in the query and it worked.

Comment: Yes. Didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 2):

For example :

Below query will bring empname column after department :

```
ALTER TABLE Employees MODIFY COLUMN empName VARCHAR(50) AFTER department;
```